# Spark throws awaitResult exception while loading Parquet file at readParquetFootersInParallel executor

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I am trying to load a parquet file in a MS Synapse Analytics Notebook. When the following error occurs.

```
df1 = spark.read.load(abfss_path+'file_name.parquet', format='parquet')
```

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1216.load.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) (vm-5fb81713 executor 1): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.parmap(ThreadUtils.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.readParquetFootersInParallel(ParquetFileFormat.scala:545)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$1(ParquetFileFormat.scala:591)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$1$adapted(ParquetFileFormat.scala:585)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SchemaMergeUtils$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$2(SchemaMergeUtils.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:870)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:870)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:374)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:338)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1491)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.parquet.bytes.BytesUtils.readIntLittleEndian(BytesUtils.java:88)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:547)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:527)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:521)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetMetadataCacheReader$.getFooter(ParquetMetadataCacheReader.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$readParquetFootersInParallel$1(ParquetFileFormat.scala:552)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.$anonfun$parmap$2(ThreadUtils.scala:372)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)
    at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:175)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2464)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2413)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2412)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2412)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1168)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1168)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1168)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2652)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2594)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2583)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:944)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2318)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2339)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2358)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2383)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1037)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1036)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SchemaMergeUtils$.mergeSchemasInParallel(SchemaMergeUtils.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.mergeSchemasInParallel(ParquetFileFormat.scala:595)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetUtils$.inferSchema(ParquetUtils.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat.inferSchema(ParquetFileFormat.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.$anonfun$getOrInferFileFormatSchema$11(DataSource.scala:210)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:281)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:253)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:190)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.parmap(ThreadUtils.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.readParquetFootersInParallel(ParquetFileFormat.scala:545)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$1(ParquetFileFormat.scala:591)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$1$adapted(ParquetFileFormat.scala:585)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SchemaMergeUtils$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$2(SchemaMergeUtils.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:870)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:870)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:374)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:338)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1491)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.parquet.bytes.BytesUtils.readIntLittleEndian(BytesUtils.java:88)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:547)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:527)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:521)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetMetadataCacheReader$.getFooter(ParquetMetadataCacheReader.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$readParquetFootersInParallel$1(ParquetFileFormat.scala:552)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.$anonfun$parmap$2(ThreadUtils.scala:372)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)
    at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:175)
```

I suspected it might have something to do with the fact I had decimal Numbers in the file, but I disabled the vectorizedReader and it still occured.
Somehow this exception occurs only sometimes and other times the Notebook run without failure.
The Notebook runs in a Synapse Pipeline and the file which I am trying to read is created in another Notebook previous to this one. Do you think it might be a problem with the Synapse pipeline running the Notebook before the file is fully written and if so, is there a solution besides implementing a wait activity?

Answer (score 0):

As per above error .Please check once whether [Storage blob contributor role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/resources-self-help-sql-on-demand?tabs=x80070002#alternative-to-storage-blob-data-contributor-role) assigned or not and then, follow below code:

[image]

**Code:**

```
%%pyspark
df = spark.read.load('abfss://<container_name>@<storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<file_Name>.parquet', format='parquet') 
display(df.limit(10))
```

[image]

Comment: The pipeline runs mostly without failure, so Data access should not be the problem. Just sometimes the Notebook fails and gives this Error and I can't define a reason on why it would fail. Since I did not change anything in between the successful run and the failure.